# why is my sprite not initializing with the image?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I'm playing around the SpriteKit and am dumbfounded by what is probably a very stupid mistake.
I am extending a SKSpriteNode, Fish, declared as such :

```
 @interface Fish : SKSpriteNode

 @property BOOL direction;
 @property FishSize fishSize;

 + (id) spriteNodeWithImageNamed : (NSString *) name;

 - (id) initWithImageNamed :(NSString *)name;
 - (void) setSize:(FishSize)s;


 @end
```

I override the spriteNodeWithImageNamed class method as such :

```
 + (id) spriteNodeWithImageNamed : (NSString *) name
 {
     Fish * f = [super spriteNodeWithImageNamed : name];
     f.direction = right;
     f.fishSize = SmallSize;
     return f;
 }
```

which is wrong because the sprite doesn't get loaded. on the other hand, if I just call the spriteNodeWithImageNamed method on a regular SKSpriteNode, it works just fine:

```
//this gets initialized to the proper size
SKSpriteNode * node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:picName];

// this is initialized to size (0,0)
Fish * fish = [Fish spriteNodeWithImageNamed:picName];
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is SmallSize ? I don't see where that is defined.

Comment: it's defined earlier in Fish.h as : `static bool left=  false;
static bool right = true;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FishSize) {
    SmallSize ,
    MediumSize,
    LargeSize
};`

Comment: Is it being used to size your fish at all ? I get the feeling we are missing some important code here. Can you post the full code of Fish.h and Fish.m as opposed to snippets you believe are relevant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is simple.

You wrote this.

```
- (void) setSize:(FishSize)s;
```

It overrides `- (void)setSize:(CGSize)size`. So size won't be initialized.
(Objective-C doesn't support method overloading.)

How about using `setFishSize:` instead?

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, that was the issue! staring me straight in the face and I couldn't see it - so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing works perfectly fine for me:

```
@interface Fish : SKSpriteNode
+ (id) spriteNodeWithImageNamed : (NSString *) name;
@end

@implementation Fish
+ (id) spriteNodeWithImageNamed : (NSString *) name
{
    Fish * f = [super spriteNodeWithImageNamed : name];
    return f;
}
@end
```

Using it like so:

```
Fish* f = [Fish spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"dummy_case.png"];
[self addChild:f];

// prints 16.0, 16.0 in my case:
NSLog(@"%f, %f", f.size.width, f.size.height);
```

The sprite is displayed as normal.

If you were referring to the `FishSize` it depends on what `FishSize` is. Is it a CGSize typedef or an enum or something else entirely?

Comment: no, I was referring to the size property on the SKSpriteNode class - the one that gets set once the image is loaded to the appropriate size of the image. It was set to 0,0 (which is how I knew something funny was going on) as opposed to the size property on the actual SKSpriteNode object, which when loaded with the image displayed the size correctly.

Comment: Size logs the correct texture size for me. Did you verify that fish isn't nil?

Comment: Fish is not nill. I literally , for my own sanity, call these 2 lines next to each other. I also re-wrote spriteNodeWithImageNamed to just call the super's method - and it returns a 0-initialized size. so these 2 lines get called together : `    SKSpriteNode * node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:picName];
    Fish * fish = [Fish spriteNodeWithImageNamed:picName];` and the last line is declared as `+ (id) spriteNodeWithImageNamed : (NSString *) name
{
    Fish * f = [super spriteNodeWithImageNamed:name];
    return f;
}`.

Comment: I can't explain why it doesn't work for you. Maybe start fresh, new project, minimal class (see my post) and check if that works. If it does keep adding your custom code, and if that works move it over to your project. There seems to be something "fishy" going on here. ;)